# sorting a list that updates in realtime

Tags: sorting, real-time-updates

I have a list of items (displayed as rectangular containers with text, numbers, buttons) that display realtime data. I want to be able to sort (and filter) these items, so that they adapt to the search in realtime, depending on their parameters. At the same time, I must be able to interact with each of the items at any time by clicking one of the buttons.

The problem:

- If I make the sort update whenever new data is received, the items may change order (and hence UI position) at any time, which makes interaction difficult.
- If I disable live updates of the search, I have to manually re-apply the search all the time, except for when I want to interact with one of the items.

Possible solutions include a "live sorting" checkbox or a hotkey to prevent live sorting while pressed, but I'm curious about other strategies for this.

Comment: Definitely sounds like you need a pause button (Pause Live Updating) if items are moving whilst users are trying to interact with them, could be extremely frustrating.

Comment: Why can't you just add a "Update" button that will fetch new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI suggestion, depending on space, which we haven't seen:

[image: UI Suggestion]

Comment: thank you for the sketch, yes i guess this will be the best option.

Comment: upvoted! does this apply for live tables?